# You are using this API without a key error on Google Places

Tags: javascript, maps

I have added an API key to my site which is working in the admin area, but when I get to the front end of the site the error 'This page can't load Google Maps correctly.' appears. In the console the following error comes up:

> You are using this API without a key. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=billing#api-key-and-billing-errors js:156:428

I have tried manually adding the script src as follows

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<api_key>&callback=initMap">
 </script>
```

and then I get an error saying I have included the API key too many times on the page, and the map still doesn't work!

I've got all of the map related APIs enabled in cloud console, and my billing is set up and working as well.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: Please generate a new API key asap, and don't publicly post your APIs again. That's not a good idea